Mongosh 2.2 mongoDB 6.0 not responding after parentheses Ubuntu 18
After a parentheses, the simply stay there and not execute.
lets say after a commands ends in () or ...) , it will just stay at that command and enter doesn't seem to trigger anything.
So when creating a new user in
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "Final",
    pwd:  "testpassone",   
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
             { role: "read", db: "reporting" } ]
  }
) <- the cursor just stays here and executes nothing 

I am trying to create a method of authentication in the mongodb instance.
I am using Using MongoDB: 6.0.15 and Mongosh: 2.2.6

Is this user the first user you create for the database after enabling authentication? The first user created after enabling authentication should always be user administrator. Otherwise, you locked yourself from creating more users/roles since you cannot use the localhost exception again

Is this your full command? What do you mean by "I am trying to create a method of authentication"? Does your password contain special characters like " or '\'?
